# Sharing internet from android to Raspberry Pi 3 is not working

Tags: networking, android, static-ip

Yesterday I set up static ip for usb0 on my raspberry pi 3. It works and i can use vnc, but i cannot share internet access to it. I have tried connecting via android wireless hotspot, but it doesnt share internet access either. I am using latest Raspbian PIXEL image - 04-10.

Comment: I've had good success using Remoter and RDP protocol to RDP into a Pi running xrdp.  Also, I use Juice for terminal access.  I have both the Pi and the tablet connected to the same WiFi router.